# Sequelize doesn't sync - insert into

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, sequelize.js

Here is my code:

`models/index.js`:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
// initialize database connection
var sequelize = new Sequelize('somedb', '', '', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  pool:{
    max: 5, 
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },
  storage: "db/main.db"
});   

// load models
var models = [
  'Users',"Clients"
];
models.forEach(function(model) {
  module.exports[model] = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/' + model);
  module.exports[model].sync();
});

// export connection
module.exports.sequelize = sequelize;
```

`app.js`:

```
SQLized.sync().then(function(err){
    //Settings Environmental Variables  
    var env = process.env.STAGE;
    var config = require("./config.js")[env];
    ...
});
```

`models/Users.js`:

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var hash = require("../modules/util/hash");

module.exports=function(sequelize, DataTypes){
  return Users = sequelize.define("Users", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      field: "id",
      autoIncrement: !0,
      primaryKey: !0
    },
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING, 
      field: "first_name"
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: "last_name"
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: "username"
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: "email"
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: "password"        
    },
    token: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: "access_token"
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      field: "isAdmin"    
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true, // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
    classMethods:{
      usernameExists: function(username, _clb){

      },
      userExists: function(username, _clb){

      },
      signup: function(params, _clb){
        var fullnm_splt = params.fullname.split(' ');
        params.firstName = (fullnm_splt.length >2) ? fullnm_splt.slice(0, -1).join(" ") : fullnm_splt[0];
        params.lastName = (fullnm_splt.length >2) ? fullnm_splt.slice(-1).join(" ") : fullnm_splt[1];

      res.redirect("/users/" + params.username);


      }
    },
    instanceMethods:{
      isValidPassword: function(password, _clb){
        var _self = this;
        hash(password, function(err, password_encr){
          if(err){
            return _clb(err);
          }
          if(password_encr == _self.password){
            return _clb(null, true);
          }

          return _clb(null, false);
        });

      }
    }
  });
};
```

`models/Clients.js`

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");

module.exports=function(sequelize, DataTypes){
  return Clients = sequelize.define("Clients", {
    id:{
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    client_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: "client_name"
    },
    client_host_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: "client_host_name"
    },  
    ip: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: "ip"
    },  
    mac: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: "mac"
    },
    previous_ip: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: "previous_ip"
    }  
  }, {      
    freezeTableName: true, // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
    classMethods:{

    },    
    instanceMethods:{

    }   
  });
};
```

When I try to save something to DB, with the function below, it states the `INSERT INTO` query in the logs but nothing changes in the db file.

`create_client`:

```
Clients
          .create({client_host_name: params.client_host_name, ip: params.ip, mac: params.mac})
          .then(function(err){
            res.send("OK");
          });
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I've tested your app, everything inserts okay check out `https://github.com/finfort/SequelizeTestRepo`